# Ternary expression does not update the jsx template

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using react-bootstrap-table-2 to build a table where I want the user to be able to change columns in a modal UI.

When a column is removed by the user the change should not take effect until the modal is closed, so until then I want the UI to reflect that the column will be removed by a strike-through of the row. So I have a ternary expression on `col.deleted` that shows the text with strike through if true.

I map over the columns array to create new rows for each column, and a button to remove the column that gets the index of the column.

```
<tbody>
  {columns.map((col: any, i: number) => (
    <tr key={i}>
      <td>{col.deleted ? <del>{col.text}</del> : col.text}</td>
      <td className="w-20">
        <div className="flex flex-row justify-center">
          <Button
            variant="danger"
            onClick={() => {
              col.deleted = !col.deleted;
              setColumns(columns);
            }}
          >
            <FaTrash />
          </Button>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  ))}
</tbody>
```

I set `columns[i].deleted` to `true` with the button but nothing gets updated in the UI. Have I misunderstood something?

Check this sandbox for the full example: https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-wilbur-q3ytt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely the issue is that you are mutating the state. Try `let newColums = [...columns];` and then perform the same things but on **newColumn**s not **columns**, and set **newColumns** in setState
I had same issue recently with a simper example and it came down to that I was mutating the state and thus the component setState was not updating the component
**EDIT** example

```
// Your onClick function
(i) => {
    let newColumns = [...columns];
    newColumns[i].deleted = !newColumns[i].deleted;
    setState(newColumns);
}
```

Your function should look somewhat like this just adjust the code in case I made typo
**Sandbox tested**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import Table from "react-bootstrap/Table";
// @ts-ignore
import cellEditFactory from "react-bootstrap-table2-editor";
// @ts-ignore
import BootstrapTable from "react-bootstrap-table-next";
import { FaTrash, FaEdit, FaPlus } from "react-icons/fa";
import { rows, columns as cols } from "./data";
import "react-bootstrap-table-next/dist/react-bootstrap-table2.min.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

export interface ColumnItem {
  dataField: string;
  text: string;
  deleted: boolean;
}

const EditTableModal = (props: any) => {
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState<ColumnItem[]>(
    props.columns.map((col: any) => {
      col.deleted = false;
      return col;
    })
  );

  const handleClick = i => {
    let newColumns = [];
    columns.forEach(column => newColumns.push(Object.assign({}, column)));
    console.log(newColumns);
    console.log(i);
    newColumns[i].deleted = !newColumns[i].deleted;
    console.log(newColumns[i].deleted);
    setColumns(newColumns);
  };
  return (
    <Modal
      {...props}
      size="lg"
      aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
      centered
    >
      <Modal.Header closeButton>
        <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
          <div className="flex flex-row items-center">
            <FaEdit className="mr-2" /> Edit columns
          </div>
        </Modal.Title>
      </Modal.Header>
      <Modal.Body>
        <Table striped bordered hover size="sm" className="mb-0">
          <tbody>
            {columns.map((col: any, i: number) => (
              <tr key={i}>
                <td>{col.deleted ? <del>{col.text}</del> : col.text}</td>
                <td className="w-20">
                  <div className="flex flex-row justify-center">
                    <Button variant="danger" onClick={() => handleClick(i)}>
                      <FaTrash />
                    </Button>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            ))}
            <tr>
              <td>
                <div>
                  <Button variant="dark">
                    <FaPlus />
                  </Button>
                </div>
              </td>
              <td className="w-20" />
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </Table>
      </Modal.Body>
      <Modal.Footer>
        <Button variant="dark" onClick={props.onHide}>
          Save
        </Button>
        <Button variant="light" onClick={props.onHide}>
          Close
        </Button>
      </Modal.Footer>
    </Modal>
  );
};

const ComponentList = () => {
  const [columns] = useState<ColumnItem[]>(cols);
  const [data] = useState<any[]>(rows);
  const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center m-3">
      {data.length > 0 ? (
        <div className="flex flex-col items-center">
          <div className="flex flex-row m-2">
            <Button
              variant="dark"
              onClick={() => setModalShow(true)}
              className="ml-1"
            >
              <div className="flex flex-row items-center">
                <FaEdit className="mr-2" /> Edit table
              </div>
            </Button>
            <EditTableModal
              show={modalShow}
              onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
              backdrop={"static"}
              columns={columns}
            />
          </div>
          <BootstrapTable
            keyField="idInternal"
            data={data}
            columns={columns}
            cellEdit={cellEditFactory({
              mode: "click",
              blurToSave: true,
              autoSelectText: true
            })}
          />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div className="font-mono text-sm">No data in table</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ComponentList;
```

Comment: I agree with your answer, but it might be helpful to show a more complete example of the correct way

Comment: I tried that as well, but then it does not seem to be able to change the deleted property, it stays the same if you check the logs in the sandbox example

Comment: oh I missed the fact you are using TS objects there, but the problem is 100% with the state beeing mutated I'm not sure how would you go about cloning the objects. So likely you will need to recreate your columns variable every time you call the onclick

Comment: I eddited my answer, it works and updates the component

Comment: Super awesome! Thanks so much!